# Under what conditions can we push-forward the differential forms on a manifold $M$ to differential forms on a manifold $N$ by a smooth map $f$?

Tags: manifolds, differential-forms, closed-form, smooth-functions, complex-manifolds

Let $M,N$ be two **Complex Manifolds** of the same (complex) dimension.

Let $f: M \longrightarrow N$ be a **Smooth Map**.

It is well-known that differential forms on the manifold $N$ can always be pulled-back to differential forms on the manifold $M$ by the map $f$.

Under what conditions can we push-forward the differential forms on the manifold $M$ to differential forms on the manifold $N$ by the map $f$?

Comment: You can form $(f_*\omega)(p) := (df(p)^{-1})^*\omega(f^{-1}(p))$ if $f$ is a diffeomorphism.

Comment: @Mason Thank you so much, but if it is a diffeomorphism then the problem is gone.

Comment: Not sure, but I think it works if $f$ is a covering map.

Comment: Yes, if $f$ is a finite covering map, you can use the fact that $df(p)$ is invertible. Then you can apply the @Mason's formula for each point in $f^{-1}(p)$ and add them up. This can be extended to a countable covering assuming that the infinite sum converges.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_along_fibers